# How to get first record in each group using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

Considering the following records:

```
   Id          F1            F2             F3 
 -------------------------------------------------
   1           Nima          1990           10
   2           Nima          1990           11
   3           Nima          2000           12
   4           John          2001           1
   5           John          2002           2 
   6           Sara          2010           4
```

I want to group by based on the `F1` field and sort by `Id` and get all fields from the first record of group similar to these records:

```
   Id          F1            F2             F3 
 -------------------------------------------------
   1           Nima          1990           10
   4           John          2001           1
   6           Sara          2010           4
```

How can I do this using linq?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

```
var res = from element in list
          group element by element.F1
              into groups
              select groups.OrderBy(p => p.F2).First();
```

Comment: So glad i found this. I got error message "The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead." from your example. Only operation on the list i did after the query was passing myResult.ToList() to a method. Using FirstOrDefault solved it though

Comment: Would it be `OrderBy(p => p.Id)`, they wanted it ordered by ID not the year column.

Comment: Can you please provider some assistance for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764687/how-to-use-linq-to-group-by-and-order-by-certain-column

Comment: What if want to retrieve the first and last item from the group?

Comment: Is there any way to project the results of this into a known type?

Answer (score 241):

```
var result = input.GroupBy(x => x.F1, (key,g) => g.OrderBy(e => e.F2).First());
```

Comment: This showed me the way using Fluent syntax.  The [overloads for GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.100).aspx) appear to give you a lot of power - one to add to the long list of learning!

Comment: @rogersillito that's why it's called a query (Language Integrated Query - LINQ), also the GroupBy has many overloads but there are just a few being commonly used, also it depends on the personal preference, such as some ones prefer to write it as `.GroupBy(x=>x.F1).Select(g=>...)`, it may look easier to understand.

Comment: similar to get the Get the **first record of a group** try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3850476/2218697) , hope helps someone.

Comment: You should replace `.First()` with `.FirstOrDefault()` or you will get the exception: `The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.`

Comment: @NikolayKostov I know about that, but I assumed the LINQ here is used as LINQ-to-object, not LINQ-to-entities, so we can safely use `.First()`. The OP's question looks really like just caring about linq-to-object, although he also tagged the question with `linq-to-entities` (not sure if he understood what that is).

Comment: i like this answer except for the fact that i cant make any sense out of it or use it

Comment: I liked this answers,Nice one.

Comment: alternatively this is equivalent `input.GroupBy(x => x.F1).Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.F2).First())`

Comment: This only returns the first group. If you want the first from each group you need to ass an additional select. (var result = input.GroupBy(x => x.F1, (key,g) => g.OrderBy(e => e.F2).Select(s => s..First());

Answer (score 15):

The awnser of @Alireza is totally correct, but you must notice that when using this code

```
var res = from element in list
          group element by element.F1
              into groups
              select groups.OrderBy(p => p.F2).First();
```

which is simillar to this code because you ordering the list and then do the grouping so you are getting the first row of groups

```
var res = (from element in list)
          .OrderBy(x => x.F2)
          .GroupBy(x => x.F1)
          .Select()
```

Now if you want to do something more complex like take the same grouping result but take the first element of F2 and the last element of F3 or something more custom you can do it by studing the code bellow

```
 var res = (from element in list)
          .GroupBy(x => x.F1)
          .Select(y => new
           {
             F1 = y.FirstOrDefault().F1;
             F2 = y.First().F2;
             F3 = y.Last().F3;
           });
```

So you will get something like

```
   F1            F2             F3 
 -----------------------------------
   Nima          1990           12
   John          2001           2
   Sara          2010           4
```

Comment: The delimiter or separator of the new object should be comma not semi colon.Please Check.

Comment: Nice part is .First() and .Last()

Comment: possibly the `First()` part is nomore supported in EFCore 3.1, you might have to materialize the data first.

Answer (score 4):

Use it to achieve what you want. Then decide which properties you want to return.

```
yourList.OrderBy(l => l.Id).GroupBy(l => new { GroupName = l.F1}).Select(r => r.Key.GroupName)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
var result = input.GroupBy(i => i.F1).Select(g => g.First());
```

You can group by multiple fields:

```
var result = input.GroupBy(i => new {i.F1, i.F2}).Select(g => g.First());
```

If you need keep order, then use lookup:

```
var result = input.ToLookup(i => i.F1).Select(g => g.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = (from element in list)
      .OrderBy(x => x.F2).AsEnumerable()
      .GroupBy(x => x.F1)
      .Select()
```

Use .AsEnumerable() after OrderBy()

Answer (score -2):

It's not exactly what you were looking for, but sometimes we look for the wrong thing because we don't know what exists. So my solution I find the most intuitiv:

```
var dict = 
input.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
     .GroupBy(x => x.F1)
     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => new { x.First().F1, x.First().F2, x.First().F3});
```

First order, then group – straight forward. Now the result of that will be a list of key-type pairs❊. As our table was already sorted, we can just pick the first entry. Also I advise to put the result in a dictionary with the ID as accessor, it's a very fast data structure to access and still flexible. Now you can access it using

```
dict[4].F1 // returns John
```

❊ technically its IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, yourType>>