# Lambda expression Join with last occurrence of right table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I have two tables `Task` and `EmpTask`.

```
Table: Task    Table: EmpTask
__________     ________________________
ID | Title     ID | TaskID  | XXXX
__________     ________________________
1  | task1     1  | 1       | emptask1
2  | task2     2  | 1       | emptask2  (this is last occurance of taskID 1)
__________     3  | 2       | emptask3    
               4  | 2       | emptask4  (this is last occurance of taskID 2)
               ________________________
```

Result expected:

```
________________________
ID | Title   | XXXX
________________________
1  | task1   | emptask2
2  | task2   | emptask4
________________________
```

I want help to write query in Lambda expression.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have written code upto this: var Tasks = db.Task.Join(TS.EmpTask, t => t.ID, et => et.TaskID, (t, et) => new { t, et })
                .Select(m => new TaskObject
                {
                    ID = m.t.ID,
                    Title = m.t.Title,
                    XXXX= m.et.XXXX,
                }); What should I add here?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about your expected result. Do you just want the **last** occurrence of an`EmpTask` related to a `Task`, or should it instead be a list of all `EmpTask` related to a `Task`?

Comment: Define "last". There's no notion of first or last if your data isn't ordered. Are you sorting your data on `ID`? or on `XXXX`?

Comment: I want a list of all the tasks - that joined with one raw from EmpTask table - that row must have max id and taskId much with id of task table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get first record in each group using Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012986/how-to-get-first-record-in-each-group-using-linq)

Comment: I checked that link. But I want  Nima -12 | John -2 | Sara - 4 as result from that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed to get the answer. Thanks for everyone helped :)

```
var result = db.Task.Join(db.EmpTask, t => t.ID, et => et.TaskID, (t, et) => new { t, et })
                    .Select(m => new  
                    {
                        ID = m.t.ID,
                        Title = m.t.Title,
                        XXXX= m.et.XXXX
                    }).GroupBy(m => m.ID, (key, g) => g.OrderByDescending(m => m.EmpTaskId).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you want `max EmpTask`.

```
var result = (from t in db.Task
         join r in db.EmpTask
                      .GroupBy(i => i.TaskID)
                      .Select(i => new { TaskID = i.Key, EmpTaskId = i.Max(t => t.ID)})
                  on t.ID equals r.TaskID
         join et in db.EmpTask on r.EmpTaskId equals et.ID
         select new
         {
            ID = t.ID,
            Title = t.Title,
            XXXX = et.XXXX
         }).ToList();
```

Lambda Expression

```
var result = db.Task.Join(
            db.EmpTask
                      .GroupBy(i => i.TaskID)
                      .Select(i => new { TaskID = i.Key, EmpTaskId = i.Max(t => t.ID)})
                  ,
            t => t.ID,
            r => r.TaskID,
            (t, r) => new { Task = t, EmpTaskTmp = r}
         ).Join(
            db.EmpTask,
            et => et.ID
            y => y.EmpTaskTmp.EmpTaskId,
            (et, y) => new { Task = y.Task, MaxEmpTask = et}
         ).Select(i => new
         {
            ID = i.Task.ID,
            Title = i.Task.Title,
            XXXX = i.MaxEmpTask.XXXX
         });
```

Comment: Could you write it in Lambda expression. Thanks